# Ruby debug output - switch on/off easily

Tags: ruby, debugging, erlang, ruby-debug, dbg

When I write draft and experimental code in Erlang I usually use this:

```
%%% Switch debugging output on/off:
-define(DBG(Str, Args), ok).
%-define(DBG(Str, Args), io:format(Str, Args)).
```

Commenting out just one line of code switches the debugging output to the console on and off.

```
?DBG("DEBUG: The function started ~n", [])
```

Thus I can use commenting in the code heavily.

Does something similar exist in Ruby?

Comment: Setting Logger.level doesn't work for you? http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/logger/1.9.2/Logger:level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby Learning's [section on logging](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_logging.html) might be helpful.